No pong for the ping! No inbox notifications for chat pings
Well, I may have moved my main-site activity elsewhere, but I still talk to people in chat here, so I very much prefer receiving notifications when they ping for me. I mean, how else will I pong them?
Pings are registered, such that they’re outlined in red, and other chat rooms I’m not currently in, are marked as having a ping. Yet the notification never ends up in the inbox, despite my user setting stating it should go there after 15 minutes of not attending to it, regardless of me being in the room.
In short: in-chat pings work, but they are not forwarded to the global inbox.
The bug has been confirmed by at least three other chat users. We’ve only tested it and confirmed it on the MSE server. According to Makyen’s test, it seems to work as expected on the SE chat server.
The bug seems to have occurred at the same time as chat room auto-leaving broke down, so it’s possibly caused by the same thing.

In testing this in the last hour, I did get a ping from chat.stackexchange.com (chat.SE) forwarded to my inbox. I did not get a ping from chat.stackoverflow.com (chat.SO) forwarded to my inbox. I did not test on chat.MSE. Given that we have at least one other issue that's been reported as happening on chat.SO and chat.MSE, but not chat.SE ("Chat search does not bring up new results", and potentially "You Shall Stay Here Forever! (aka chat auto leave isn't working anymore)") it seems likely this may be similar, and probably the same underlying issue.

@Makyen Chat auto leave broken was first noticed in The Tavern by me, which was followed by a support ticket by Yahav, then the MSE post from him replacing it. We’ve only observed these issues in the MSE chat, as neither us have used the SO chat in a long time.

hypothetically, you wouldn't get inbox pings if you were in a room, and if chat stopped detecting that you were offline, you'd not get pings?

@JourneymanGeek They are still supposed to end up in the inbox if the pings aren’t attended to, despite being online in the room.

@AndreasmovedtoCodidact With reference to your edit summary, I remember seeing "despite the my user setting stating" and thinking it was odd when I fixed the other typo, but I could not be sure that it was a typo and so I left it as it was. I am surprised to see that my edit somehow reintroduced that typo by adding "the".

@PeterJames Oh, don’t worry about that. My edit summary was sarcasm; I know you didn’t reintroduce it on purpose. We happened to edit at the same time, so we both edited the same revision, then yours was committed after mine, effectively undoing mine. Comment edit: oh, yours didn’t roll back the link fix I did. Well, anyway.
